# How to dynamically change the colors of filling in JavaFx 8 area chart depending on whether negative or positive values

Tags: charts, javafx, stacked-area-chart

I need a area chart that can stylize the chart fill in a different color (red, e.g.) when this be negative.

How to do it in JavaFX?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSl5a.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nzag3.png

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way to achieve this is to create two `XYCHartSeries` for your Chart. 
One for the negative values and one for the positives. Then you can set the color of the ChartSeries with CSS like this:
`positiveChart.setId("positiveValues");
        positiveChart.setStyle("#positiveValues {-fx-bar-fill: #4CAF50 }");`

Comment: I even thought about it, but at the chart remain the same as the previous example I need to find out the exact location of the intersection of the series on the x axis.

Comment: Maybe u can iterate through the data of your chart. Something like this:   for(int i = 0 ; i < xyChartSeries.getData().size(); i++){
   System.out.println(xyseries1.getData().get(i));
  }   and then apply the css for each data in this loop ?

Comment: In this way I could change only the symbols of negative values. For the line and the fill change occurs for the entire series.